# Cassandra pagination inside partition

Tags: cassandra, pagination, cql, wide-column-store

How can I paginate data inside partition? I can`t use token for this, so I made microtime field with creation time and ordered records by it. Now I am slicing data using '<' and '>' and it makes a lot of constraints for my queries. Is there better way to do this?

Comment: do you mean pagination to output data to web page, or something like? If yes, do you need both forward & backward pagination?

Comment: Yes, I want to output it in datatable on webpage. Its hard to make pagination with numbers, but I need at least 'prev' and 'next' pages.

Comment: I'd like to use tokens with uuids, but I didn`t find built-in database solution for sorting records from newer to older.

Answer (score 3):

For forward pagination, most of drivers (I definitely know about Java & Node.js) have notion of [paging](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/paging/). You're basically execute your query, but set fetch size to value of number of entries that you want to have on page. You can [grab current "paging state"](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/paging/#saving-and-reusing-the-paging-state) and set it into cookier, or hidden form parameter of the page, and restore it when user clicks on "next" button, so you can retrieve next page.

Backward paging is more tricky, but is also doable - basically, you need to store somewhere the value of the clustering key(s) for first record that you output on previous page, and then execute query like `select * from table where partition_key = value and clustering_column > value`.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Am I correct that if a user has gone from page 1 to page 4 and now wants to go back to page 3,2,1 then the first record for each previous page (3,2,1) need to be stored in the application.

Comment: yes. but not record, but a primary key for that record.  Or you can use `OffsetPager` class from the Java driver 4.9+ - if your pages are fit into a single "Cassandra page"

Comment: out of curiosity, would it work if I store the `paging state` which was received when the previous page was delivered? How does `Cassandra` track that a paging state if valid?

Comment: Also, my application doesn’t need random page navigation. It would be linear (previous page and next pager only) so am I correct that the performance impact would be negligible or none?